# Uploading Hashmap Variable to Firebase Database

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I'm creating an element in my Hashmap that holds photo path of a photo that is uploaded from my phone's storage to Firebase storage. If I uploaded more than one photo, there should be an element (image 1, image 2, image 3,.....) in my Hashmap that holds the the photo paths depending on the number of photos being uploaded.

Every time I'll run the program the other elements of the Hashmap "Name, Email" will be uploaded, but the photo path ("image"+i) doesn't upload.

I want the end result to be look like this in the database:
[the end result in Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2WzO.jpg)

Is there any bug in my work? Is there anyway that makes this work?

This is my code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button mSelectimage;
    private StorageReference mStorage;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private Uri image;
    private String photoPath;
    final static int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
    int i;
    int j;
    int totalItelmsSelected;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSelectimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mSelectimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
                startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        final HashMap <Object,Object> datamap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

        if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            if(data.getClipData() != null){

                totalItelmsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

                for(i=0; i < totalItelmsSelected; i++){

                    image = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                    final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("photos").child(image.getLastPathSegment()+".jpg");
                    filepath.putFile(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                            photoPath = filepath.getPath();
                            datamap.put("image "+i , photoPath);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, i+" Photos has been uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in Uploading "+i+" Photos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                datamap.put("Name", "Kamil");
                datamap.put("Email", "Kamil@gmail.com");

               mDatabase.child("users").push().setValue(datamap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading to the database is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in registuring the information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammed.storemultipleimages"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:11.8.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: give us grandle files too please, maybe is problem with firebase version

Comment: try .push().updateChildren(datamap)  intead of setValue()

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos Done

Comment: @KamilAhmed try my answer and tell me if it works

Comment: @JinsonPaul it is not working, since the Hashmap is being modified before it is being uploaded to the database.

Comment: @KamilAhmed I added an answer please check

Comment: @ParaskevasNtsounos Still, the other variables "Name, Email" are being uploaded to the Firebase Database, but not the multiple PhotoPaths.

Comment: @JinsonPaul I tried to do it,  when I choose 2 photos, it will upload 2 sets of data both have the same Name and Email,but Different PhotoPaths. I want these different PhotoPaths to be inside the same set of data, not separated.

Comment: @KamilAhmed try the new edited answer,, If worked please mention

Comment: @JinsonPaul it uploaded only one path, it didn't upload two paths. Please check the photo in the question to get a better idea. I really appreciate your help and would love it if it solved :(

Comment: @KamilAhmed replace setValue with updateChildren in my final Answer

Comment: @JinsonPaul The same problem, when I upload 2 photos, it only takes a path of one photo. it doesn't put 2 paths.

Comment: @KamilAhmed  the code to update database looks fine .. are you sure the two photos are getting uploaded. And please try to replace "image " with "image" remove the space

Comment: Remove the space in "image "

Comment: @JinsonPaul The same problem, please check my latest answer for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use latest version of google-services like (Project level):

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

And replace your existing code with below:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mohammed.storemultipleimages"
        minSdkVersion 26
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button mSelectimage;
private StorageReference mStorage;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private Uri image;
private String photoPath;
final static int GALLERY_INTENT = 2;
int i;
int j;
int totalItelmsSelected;
String push_id;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mSelectimage = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    push_id = mDatabase.child("users").push().getKey();

    mSelectimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);
            startActivityForResult(intent, GALLERY_INTENT);
        }
    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    final HashMap <Object,Object> datamap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        if(data.getClipData() != null){

            totalItelmsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

            for(i=0; i < totalItelmsSelected; i++){

                image = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("photos").child(image.getLastPathSegment()+".jpg");
                filepath.putFile(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        photoPath = filepath.getPath();
                        datamap.put("image "+i , photoPath);
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, i+" Photos has been uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        datamap.put("Name", "Kamil");
                        datamap.put("Email", "Kamil@gmail.com");

                        mDatabase.child("users").child(push_id).setValue(datamap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading to the database is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in registuring the information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        });

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in Uploading "+i+" Photos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }


        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that when you are putting image in storage, this process occurs asynchronously. So before putting image in storage and adding uri in hashmap, method on firebase database is being called:

So you have to make sure that before calling method on firebase you have completed the hashmap process:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    final HashMap <Object,Object> datamap = new HashMap<Object, Object>();

    if(requestCode == GALLERY_INTENT && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        if(data.getClipData() != null){

            totalItelmsSelected = data.getClipData().getItemCount();

            for(i=0; i < totalItelmsSelected; i++){

                image = data.getClipData().getItemAt(i).getUri();
                final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("photos").child(image.getLastPathSegment()+".jpg");
                filepath.putFile(image).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {

                        photoPath = filepath.getPath();
                        datamap.put("image "+i , photoPath);
                        datamap.put("Name", "Kamil");
                        datamap.put("Email", "Kamil@gmail.com");

                      mDatabase.child("users").push().setValue(datamap).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                           @Override
                           public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Uploading to the database is done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                           @Override
                           public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in registuring the information", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                           }
                       });
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, i+" Photos has been uploaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Problem in Uploading "+i+" Photos.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Should it make a difference if I completed the Hashmap inside the loop or outside the loop? Should I add all elements to the Hashmap one after another before uploading it to Firebase Database? I can't add data to the Hashmap randomly and then upload it all together?

Comment: You didn't get me. what I was saying is that before running `datamap.put("image "+i , photoPath)` your application was running `datamap.put("Name", "Kamil")`, `datamap.put("Email", "Kamil@gmail.com")` and ` mDatabase.child("users")........`. so your photo path was being put in hashmap after you called firebase database. just get some hands on java asynchronous, then you will get it.